# IIS 10.0 (Windows Server 2019) For all web pages returns blank page with all feature installed

Tags: iis, iis-10, windows-server-2019

Good morning.
I have seen several topics about the same problem in the forums. But applying the tips equally I can't get it to work for me.
I have contracted Windows Server 2019 in the Azure portal, it has IIS 10. I installed all the IIS options, but for any type of content it returns a blank page, even for simple HTML files.
I have installed all the IIS options, restart the server, configure the web page with 1 file index.html, but it doesn't work, it only returns a blank page.

What could be left to do?

IIS configuration:

[image]

P.S. The default IIS website does not work either.

When my configuration of binding is port 80

[image]

I get this in local and in remote

[image]

If I change it to the port 8081

[image]

I get different bad result

[image]

When I test port 80 for my website with Fiddler, I get this error 401

[image]

Comment: I ran into the same, did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: My case was resolved https://serverfault.com/questions/1130803/wcf-web-service-response-blank-on-window-server-2019-but-the-same-release-works/1132386#1132386

Answer (score 0):

Is the machine's port of the current website occupied by another website/webserver? such as `Nginx`,`Apache`.
Besides, I suspect there is something wrong with your network interface since Azure VM has Azure’s networking rules. We have to configure it if we use non-standard ports. 
Finally, How do you verify if the website works? Have you tested it locally? Please share the website configuration here.
Here is mine.
[image]
Then I test it http://localhost:8008/, it works properly.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Is clear server. I don't have any server installed like nginx and apache. I test to change to 8081 that port and webbrowser don't see the website. I test it in local and remote. Is same result. See my question, I change and add images, in the comment is not possible add images for me.

Comment: Please remove the hostname and use `localhost` or 127.0.0.1 to visit the local website before you confirm that your domain name points to local IP. If you want to visit the website through the specified domain name or machine name, you need to know DNS

Comment: I test it with local host and 127.0.0.1 and have same problem. Nothing change.

Comment: What about the pages on the other website? Besides, please ensure the anonymous authentication is enabled in the IIS authentication module due to I saw the HTTP 401 error displayed in the Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS 8.5, blank page behavior are usually cause by Anonymous authentication enabled and Windows authentication disabled.

Not sure why: No HTTP 500 error page, no error in the event log, not even an URL listed in Chrome debug/network.